# Can a cast a nullable column to a NOT NULL column?

Tags: sql-server, null

In SQL 2005/8 I'm looking to convert a column in select query to a NOT NULL column.

`coalease()` and `isnull()`, although fine functions, is not what I'm looking for. I want the select to throw an error is any of the data is NULL.

Is this possible?

[Update] 
Clearly the best approach would be to modify the source table, unfortunatly in this case, it's not a (cost-effective) option.

Comment: If the query should error on nulls...it means nulls don't belong. Why not just put a not null constraint on the column?

Comment: When would you like the select to throw a null?  The null constraint option sounds like the best idea, and just catch the error if it comes back. This should only be a one time activity, right?

Comment: What type of error do you want?  t-Sql error?

Comment: For anyone puzzled by a real world example. I came across this issue with a VIEW (containing SELECT) where I know the 'primary key' column won't ever be null but it's still shown in the column list (in SSMS) as being `int null`. This causes havoc with inefficient generated SQL (EFCore) based on the view. Yes there is another underlying issue with the source data also being nullable but I needed to force it for the view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An odd request, but I think this fulfils it:

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    Val VARCHAR(100) NULL
)

INSERT INTO @TABLE(Val)
SELECT 'Hello' 
UNION SELECT 'World' 
UNION SELECT NULL --Remove this line to prevent failure

SELECT 
  ID, 
  CASE WHEN Val IS NULL THEN CAST(1/0 AS VARCHAR) ELSE Val END AS ValCheck 
FROM @TABLE
```

Comment: Awesome - nice way to work around the limitations of the language.

Answer (score 7):

What you ask for doesn't exists.

NOT NULL is a **constraint**. SELECT statements do not enforce constraints. Constraints are only enforced during INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE of the data. If you need to enforce a constraint, declare the constraint on the table, via ALTER TABLE ... ADD...

If you want to return non-null data, use a null translation function like ISNULL or COALESCE.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to throw an error in the (non-sql) code side, your kind-of only option is

```
$result = db.query("SELECT count(1) FROM table WHERE column_that_should_not_be_null IS NULL")
assert($result = 0);
```

If you want to transform the column to not accept `NULL`, when you do the `ALTER TABLE ... SET NOT NULL`, you'll get an error.